# Phototelectric smoke sensor with microcontroller

Tags: atmega, impedance, input, smoke-sensor

I am trying to connect a photoelectric smoke sensor with Atmega328. The smoke sensor IC has pin 7 as the I/O pin which gives a 9V when smoke is detected. I have connected this pin to the input pin of the micro-controller through a simple potential divider. But when I connect the sensor to micro it gives false alarm after some time and works fine when independent. 
I have kept all the wires short to avoid any capacitive loading and have internally pulled down the pin.
Any leads where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is the voltage on the sensor pin correct without the divider and microcontroller? Is it correct after the divider but without the microcontroller?

Comment: yes it is correct after divider.

Comment: If you have "internally pulled down the pin" (or pull up the pin), it put a loading on the voltage divider. You can check the voltage is correct after divided WITH MCU connected. If you get good voltage without connection and low voltage with connection to MCU, then, it shows loading. The R should be in tens of kilo ohm range, if pull up enabled.

Comment: Check the voltage on the µC pin while everything is connected. It should read 0V. If it doesn't, make sure you have set the µC pin to *input* with *no* pull-up. Otherwise there may be 5V going from the µC to the (normally low) I/O of the detector, which triggers the remote alarm feature. - And, by the way, did you connect the two grounds to each other?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your resistor divider chain loads the output too heavily.  Just increase the sizes of the resistors while maintaining the ratio to correct this if it the problem.

Comment: have tried value upto 3.9M....(potential divider of two 3.9M resistors)

Answer (score 0):

After the resistor divider put an opamp in buffer configuration.

The IC probably is MC145010 and if that is true, I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work with the resistor divider... you could try a diode clamp. Ignore Vmax-0.7 and Vmin+0.7 in the image. Just tie upper node to Vcc and the lower node to GND. R doesn't have to be a high value, 1k will work fine.

If possible try to use schottky diodes.

[image: clamp diode]

Comment: i do not have much details of detector chip as it a chinese one ..the number says xc5010dw.I could not find datasheet in english but as with other detector chips pin7 is a I/O pin and gives 8-9 volts on pressing test button.